# Как получить доступ к элементам динамического массива по ссылке?

Tags: c++

Есть динамический массив объектов, как передать его в функцию и получить доступ к отдельному элементу?

```
Animal *arr = new Animal[counter];

Foo(*arr);

void Foo (Animal &arr) {

  cout << arr[3].x; // Тут ошибка
}
```

Comment: Animal *arr заменить ссылку на указатель?

Comment: Это какая-то XY проблема. С чего это вдруг вы вообще взялись передавать массив как `Animal &arr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы указали аргументом функции ссылку на Animal, у которого потом пытаетесь вызвать `operator[]`, скорее всего компилятор на это вам и указал в ошибке... Если вы хотите передавать массив, передавайте в функцию, например, указатель+размер массива.

```
void Foo(Animal* arr, size_t size)
{
    //тут надо бы проверить, что size > 3
    cout << arr[3].x;
}
```

Хотя, разумеется, вы можете выкрутиться как-то так:

```
void Foo(Animal& arr)
{
    cout << (&arr)[3].x;
}
```

Но это уже мягко говоря извращение...

Answer (score 0):

```
Animal *arr = new Animal[counter];

Foo(arr);

void Foo (Animal *arr) {

 cout << arr[3].x;
}
```